# Count number of days from a date then convert that count to a date-time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to count the number of days from a date from a date-time column, let's say one of the value is '10/31/2018' and I want to count up to 30 days. So in perspective it would look like '11/30/2018' in a new column. How do I convert that count to a date-time value?

I can't get my head around this and I been trying to solve this. Any help would be great!

edit: Now suppose I want to add 30 days, 60 days and 90 days. How do I do that in the same line of code adding new columns for each count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use dateadd

```
select dateadd(d,30, '10/31/2018')
```

if your column it date from table tbl, you do

```
select *
, dateadd(d,30,date) as date30 
, dateadd(d,60,date) as date60 
, dateadd(d,90,date) as date90 
, dateadd(d,xx,date) as datexx 
from tbl
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this will solve for what I was looking for.

Comment: @Leonardo, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.

Comment: First part solved. Now suppose I want to add 30 days, 60 days and 90 days. How do I do that in the same line of code adding new columns for each count? and @EricBrandt will do !

Comment: Look at my improved reply. Same trick really, copy/pste and few changes Leo